# how to unzip the latest file only

Tags: ftp, unzip

am downloading daily FTP File through the following command:

```
wget -mN --ftp-user=myuser --ftp-password=mypassword ftp://ftp2.link.com/ -P /home/usr/public_html/folder/folder2
```

my file structure are like this:

- Data_69111232_2016-01-29.zip
- Data_69111232_2016-01-28.zip
- Data_69111232_2016-01-27.zip

can you please let me know how can extract only the latest downloaded file only

usually am using the following command to unzip the file, but i don't know what should i add to extract only the latest file

```
unzip -o /home/user/public_html/folder/folder2/ftp2.directory/????.zip -d /home/user/public_html/folder/folder2/
```

you help is really approciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I thought your question was about FTP, but it is maybe about finding the newest file to unzip.

You can get the newest file like this:

```
newest=$(ls -t /home/user/public_html/folder/folder2/ftp2.directory/*zip | head -1)
```

and see the value like this:

```
echo $newest
```

and use it like this:

```
unzip -o "$newest" ...
```

**Original Answer**

You can probably string something together using `lftp`. For example, I can get a listing in reverse time order with the newest file at the bottom like this:

```
lftp -e 'cd path/to/daily/file; ls -lrt; bye' -u user,password host | tail -1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem that i want to Unzip command only unzip the new archive, because we daily download the file which i mentioned in my question and keep them,  i think i need regular expression in my Unzip command

Comment: I have had another try, please look again.

Comment: Hi i have another question the command which you have provided is working perfectly if i execute them manually but when am trying to put them in shell script,to be executed automatically daily they not working, i got unzip cannot find the specific file which we need. Can you help me with that Thanks

Comment: Try echoing the value to a log file before you use it, e.g. `latest=$(...); echo $latest >> /tmp/log.txt`

Comment: by the way am using CentOS :)

Comment: i found some tips online that i have to write the scrip in text editor (but not a word processor), such as gedit or vi, and simply it's work i don't what the difference http://www.linfo.org/create_shell_1.html

Comment: Click `edit` under your question and paste in your actual script. You may have a space by the equals sign or something the shell doesn't like.